# PHP mysql query issue when filtering from array and variables

Tags: php, html, mysql

On my webpage (html, php), I'm trying to get it such that users may select multiple checkboxes, each checkbox effectively filters what results the users see. Info is pulled from the database (MySQL) based on the values in different columns. As shown below, one column is Joint_1, another column is Position.

Effective code that WORKS for filtering (very static, not practical to use obviously) is this:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `Table_Name` WHERE (Joint_1=\'region1\'  OR  
                                          Joint_1=\'region2\'  OR  
                                          Joint_1=\'region3\' OR
                                          Joint_1=\'region4\') AND
                                         (Position=\'position1\' OR
                                          Position=\'position2\' OR
                                          Position=\'position3\')";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if($result->num_rows > 0) {
   while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
      echo $row["Common_Name1"] . "<br>";
   }
} else {
  echo "0 results";
  }
```

Below code is attempts at above code, but using arrays, which does NOT work.

```
$regions = 
array('region1', 'region2', 'region3', 'region4');
$position = array('position1', 'position2', 'position3');

$sql = "SELECT * FROM `Table_Name` WHERE (Joint_1=\'. $regions[0] .\'  OR  
                                          Joint_1=\'. $regions[1] .\'  OR  
                                          Joint_1=\'. $regions[2] .\' OR
                                          Joint_1=\'. $regions[3] .\') AND
                                         (Position=\'. $position[0] .\' OR
                          Position=\'. $position[0] .\' OR
                      Position=\'. $position[0] .\')";
```

Above code provides results of '0 results.'

I've attempted to perform this numerous times, with additional NON-FUNCTIONAL CODE also below (below attempting to filter based on only 1 column as I have obviously not mastered the code to approach filtering based on 2 columns).

```
$sqlregion = array();
foreach ($_POST['region'] as $reg) {
   $sqlreg[] = "'" . mysql_real_escape_string($reg) . "'";   
}
$sql = "SELECT * FROM 'Exercises' WHERE Joint_1 IN (" . implode(",", 
$sqlreg) . ");";

$result=$conn->query($sql);

if($result->num_rows > 0) {
   while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
     echo $row["Common_Name1"] . "<br>";
   } 
}
```

Any help is appreciated! Thanks.

Comment: If 'region1' is working in the code then why would your array have 'Region_value1' are they supposed to be the same?

Comment: But as way code is written, it is appropriate that $region[0] = Region_value1, Region[1] = Region_value2, etc... but point is that value of $region[0] doesn't seem to work in the code I have.

Comment: Thanks again Funk Doc for bringing up what was obvious after you point it out... original post edited to clear ambiguity. Code continues to provide no results, I'm pretty sure I do not know proper syntax when incorporating arrays into sql code.

Comment: Miknik, I modified code slightly to keep code easier to read. In my code, everything is consistent and shouldn't limit answering the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can construct this query from arrays, you can use the `IN` clause in mysql to specify multiple `OR` values

```
$regions = array('region1', 'region2', 'region3', 'region4');
$position = array('position1', 'position2', 'position3');
$regions = implode(",", $regions); // Converts array to string with comma as a separator
$position = implode(",", $position);
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `Table_Name` WHERE Joint_1 IN ($regions) AND Position IN ($position)";
echo $sql;
```

This gives you a query like this

```
SELECT * FROM Table_Name WHERE Joint_1 IN (region1,region2,region3,region4) AND Position IN (position1,position2,position3)
```

add in your own `LIMIT` `GROUP BY` or `ORDER BY` parameters to suit your needs

Comment: Thanks Miknik, I'll give it a try here in just little bit!

Comment: Had to add quotation marks around the string in the array (line 1 of the code you provided), i.e. $regions = array("'region1'", "'region2'", etc) so the query in php had the quotation marks around those, i.e. echo $sql produced the ...WHERE Joint_1 IN ('region1','region2'...etc). But yes, works great now, thanks so much!

Comment: You're welcome. I notice in your code the only column you are echoing to the page from the query is `$row[Common_Name1]`. When making database queries it's much faster if you only retrieve the data you want, so instead of `SELECT *` (which returns every column) you should use `SELECT Common_Name1` instead. You can specify multiple columns by separating them with a comma. Again, you'll have to add quotes, I cant do it here without screwing the code formatting